# rasberry pi unrecoverable fatal error

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-4

this is what  i get when i do sudo apt-get upgrade .

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  arandr bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs dnsutils gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gtk-update-icon-cache libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-common libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libmutter-7-0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 lighttpd lxplug-bluetooth lxplug-netman lxplug-network mutter mutter-common raspberrypi-sys-mods raspberrypi-ui-mods raspi-config
23 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/30.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,270 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'keyutils' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

hello i am trying to this upgrade and keep getting this message. Any suggestion how to fix this.

i have tried

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install and sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade and  sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean
```

nothing working. Still getting this error. pi 4 with pihole running

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post ... did you read the error message?

Comment: Hi i am sorry . this is what  i get when i do sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Hi i am sorry . I have changed the the test with whole message i am getting. I am trying to update Pi. I had a power outage during last update i think that may have corrected the file. I am not sure. i am just trying to avoid re-building the pi.  sorry for the confusing question i dint understand the error.

Comment: Searching for the error message `files list file for package 'keyutils' is missing final newline` led me to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/947374/1186757

Comment: or:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1297028/154031