# Dpkg fatal error - Rasberry Pi - Re-post Need help please

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I don't know what is the problem. I have tried using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get clean`; still getting the same error. I did post this 2 days ago but the formatting got all messed-up, tried to fix it but unable to fix. so i am posting it again.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  arandr bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs dnsutils gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gtk-update-icon-cache libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-common
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libmutter-7-0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 lighttpd
  lxplug-bluetooth lxplug-netman lxplug-network mutter mutter-common
  raspberrypi-sys-mods raspberrypi-ui-mods raspi-config rpi-eeprom tzdata
25 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,759 kB/32.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 5,844 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main arm64 tzdata all 2021a-1+deb11u6 [284 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 rpi-eeprom arm64 13.17-2 [1,475 kB]
Fetched 1,759 kB in 2s (1,158 kB/s)                          
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'keyutils' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/139351/rasberry-pi-unrecoverable-fatal-error

Comment: If you want help register do not ask duplicate question and See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Let me [google that for you.](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=files+list+file+for+package+%27keyutils%27+is+missing+final+newline&atb=v278-1&ia=web) Sometimes, simply putting the error message in a search engine may yield the answer you're looking for. Several of the results in this search have positive feedback that the answers resolved their issue. N.B. ***I have not tried these solutions myself.***

##### To summarize:

The problem is that one or more of the `*.list` files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` is corrupted. There are two general approaches described for resolving this file corruption issue:

**Approach I:** The corrective action [from this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1297028/831935) is to:

1. find the corrupted file(s) at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/keyutils.list`, and verify that it is corrupted. `*.list` files should be text files whose last character is a *newline* `\n`.
2. Remove/delete the corrupted file(s),
3. Reinstall using `sudo apt install <names-of-packages> --reinstall`

**Approach II:** This manual process can become tedious if there are multiple corrupted files (there are typically many files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`). There is an *automated* solution in the form of a [Python script named `newline_fixer.py` from this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/gautric/8c7ee5380ea216acf1f9). This simple Python script has also been prescribed in [this Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39665055/5395338), and [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1319791), and probably other sources.

Note that this automated solution ***does not*** delete any `*.list` files, and does not require re-installation. Instead, it compares the last character in the file against the *newline* character; it appends a single newline to the file in the event the comparison is false.

**Which Approach to Use?** Reading through the Questions, answers and comments in all of the above it seems that the file corruption may fall into one of two categories:

- Category 1. The `.list` file is badly corrupted; perhaps a binary file.
- Category 2. The `.list` file is simply missing a newline as the final character.

The Approach to use should be based on the *corruption category*:

- For Category 2 corruption, the Python script linked in **Approach II** seems likely to resolve the issue with a minimum of time and effort.
- Otherwise, if the file corruption is more extensive than a missing *newline*, **Approach I** - or some variant thereof - will have to be used. One of the answers provided in [the search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=files+list+file+for+package+%27keyutils%27+is+missing+final+newline&atb=v278-1&ia=web) suggests some automation in the form of a [shell script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1348112/831935) to identify the presence of binary characters in the `.list` files. However, I would review the `grep` test for **binary** in that script [in light of the information here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary).